# ScalaTest Maven Plugin Does not Detect Scala Test Suite

Tags: scala, maven

I have the following configured in the parent pom of my multi module Maven project.

```
             <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.7</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                      <useFile>false</useFile>
                      <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                      <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,...-->
                      <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
                      <includes>
                          <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                          <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                          <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                      </includes>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- enable scalatest -->
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDFTestSuite.txt</filereports>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>test</id>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Nothing fancy here as it is just straight out the same configuration settings that could be found under the Scalatest documentation. But strangely, running the following does not detect any of my scala tests:

```
mvn clean install

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ My-Project ---
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 103 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 0
DiscoverySuite:
Run completed in 160 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 0
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
No tests were executed.
```

Is there anything that I'm missing in the form of any configuration?

EDIT:

Here is how my project is structured:

parent-project

- pom.xml
- src

  - main

    - scala
    - java
- child-project

  - pom.xml
  - src

    - main
    - test

      - scala
      - java

Comment: Are you following canonical directory structure with your test files in `./src/test/scala`?

Comment: Obviously I'm following it.

Comment: can you show an example of dir structure from root of the project and also how you name your test files. Looks like something doesn't match up there.

Comment: I have edited my post. The test class is in the child project, inside the src/test/scala folder

Comment: Are you running `maven` from root or child-project? I assume from child-project it should be fine. Try setting `skipTests` to true

Comment: I'm running it from my child project and having the plugin configutration in the parent pom

Comment: skipTests to true would not even run the JUnit tests that I have in the src/test/java folder

Comment: just to see if it can find scala tests

Comment: I think there is some bug in this and I'm not sure if I'm the only one to face this issue?

Comment: (parent-pom) build>plugins or build>pluginManagement ??

Comment: (pluginManagement doesn't "add" any executions, it only "configures"/declares them)

Comment: It is inside build -> plugin and not inside pluginManagement